# System fields in JSON request body

Tags: json, rest, schema

I am preparing dynamic JSON request body for the contact object fields using  `Schema.getGlobalDescribe` class, but i am getting all the system fields in the request body like 
 
`CreatedDate, IsDeleted, CreatedById, LastModifiedById, SystemModstamp, LastReferencedDate and so on.` 

 How to exclude this filed names in the JSON request body.

Comment: You can try with fieldset. You will get more control on the fields.

Comment: Best would be to use wrapper class and cast the field as properties, then deserialize the object or list.